# What is more Pythonic way to handle try-except errors?

Tags: python

I have two different options in mind:

```
def foo():
    try:
        # do something interesting
    except:
        # report error here
    
    return bar

bar = foo()
```

or

```
def foo():
    # do something
    return bar

try:
    bar = foo()

except:
    # report error here
```

Is there a preferred way to do this? If so, is there a specific reason or is it simply a matter of convention? I'm curious if I'm missing something obvious here.

Here is a real-world example if generic version is confusing:

```
my_dict = {}
def fetch_value(key):
    try:
        return my_dict[key] #This would throw a KeyError
    except KeyError:
        print("problem")

val = fetch_value('my_key')
```

vs

```
my_dict = {}
def fetch_value(key):
    return my_dict[key]

try:
    val = fetch_value('my_key') #This would throw a KeyError
except KeyError:
    print("problem")
```

Comment: That's not a real world example because you should just inline `fetch_value`. A lot of this decision comes down to whether you want every caller of `fetch_value` to throw an exception or not, but as you've got only one caller that becomes irrelevant.

Comment: You will notice that your first `fetch_value()` example might not work as you expect. You're still assigning a value to `val`, but it will silently be `None`. Pylint would have warned you about the invisible return.

Comment: The first one has the advantage of not repeating any code when handling errors. The second one has the advantage that the code to handle errors can be tailored to the caller's needs. So if the error handling code will be the always be the same, use the first one; otherwise use the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of these is more Pythonic than the other.  The examples are too trivial to say which is preferrable but it really all depends on how things should work.

Catch and logging/reporting an issue is just a hair's breadth away from squashing exceptions which is almost always a terrible idea.  The only reason I can see doing this is that you want whatever the issue is to not stop execution.  If you are going to do something like this, it's really crucial to make sure that you return something sensible that works for the caller.  If the next thing that happens is that the calling code throws its own exception because e.g., `None` doesn't have an `add` method, you are at best just making things harder to troubleshoot.  It could be a lot worse, however.  A lot of serious bugs are due to returning nulls/None after catching an error.  I think there are times that is makes sense to do this, but they are rare in my experience.

Allowing the raw exception to bubble out is the next least-worst option, IMO.  This can be fine if you are building something small where it will be easy to find the what the problem is when things crash with a `KeyError`.  In a situation where you are leveraging a lot of duck-typing, passing around function references, or using annotations, it can sometimes be difficult.  For example, if you are using this code behind a web endpoint, what HTTP error code should you use when you catch a `KeyError`.  500 might be the right answer in most cases but there might be times you want to produce something else depending on where the key was not found.

That brings me to the last option which you don't mention: catch and raise a separate, more meaningful error.  That allows you to distinguish between say, a `KeyError` thrown because the request was for something that isn't valid and a `KeyError` thrown because of a bad configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is pythonic. Pythonic code would be:

```
my_dict = {}
def fetch_value(key):
    return my_dict[key]

val = fetch_value('my_key')
```

Remember, simple is better than complex and flat is better than nested. Since your `except`-block does not handle the exception in any meaningful way, it is better to just let it bubble up the call stack and terminate the program.

But in your code the error is ignored and it implicitly returns `None` if the key is not found. If this is what you want, then it can be done simpler with the get() method:

```
def fetch_value(key):
    return my_dict.get(key)
```

"Handling" an error by just logging a message and then continuing as if nothing happened, is a terrible antipattern from the Java world which has no place in Python. Exceptions should only be caught if they can be meaningfully handled.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with being "Pythonic" (or not) - it is not a question of idioms and conventions, but of requirements and context.

Whether a function includes their own exception handling, or lets the caller handle it's exception, depends solely on how the designer of the function wants the function to be used and reused:

- if the function shall be called in different contexts, with the option of letting different callers handle errors differently, use option 2 ("exception handling outside")
- if the function shall always handle it's error in the very same way, regardless from where it is called, use option 1 ("exception handling inside").

And in case you need both, a function which often contains it's own error handling, but not always, you are free to implement two functions - one "inner function" `foo` with no own exception handling, and one outer function `foo2` which wraps the call to `foo` into some standard error handling.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean

Comment: I agree it is vague.  It is a thing, though.  I thought maybe you just hadn't seen the term.  That seems silly now, though.  I'm a little under the weather.

Comment: @candied_orange: doesn't matter, whaever Pythonic means in detail for you or me, it is not a suitable decision criterion for this question.